# Log all IO activity for a specific program

Tags: file-management, logs, disk-analysis

I'm looking for a way to find out which file a program reads or modifies and save all that to a log file. This is a pretty simple task by itself, but I can't find any apps that do it, surprisingly.

Required features:

- Filter by process or only show activity for the selected process;
- Show full path of the accessed file;
- Show operation type (read/write);
- Write log in real time.

Time of operation would be nice, but not necessary.

There are apps like Process Explorer which kinda show the file handles for a moment, but they don't provide logging, so most of the operations are missing from display and it's somewhat difficult to automate saving the view to file every second, so it's a no-go.

The OS is Windows 7.

Comment: What about [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  Have you looked into that?

Comment: Which OS are you looking to do this for and are you looking to deploy to users machines or are you testing one specific programme?

Comment: @rrirower I couldn't get it to run. It says "Process Monitor is obsolete now, so use Process Explorer instead" and shuts down. I was very upset. Oh wait you just linked to a working version :D This is actually great!

Comment: I don't know why that is.  I just ran it on Windows 8.1 and it ran correctly.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: @rrirower you can post an answer with that. This is a fine tool to get just what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windows Sysinternals** provides a tool called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).  The name is unfortunate because it is often confused with "Process Explorer".  However, it has the features you've requested including filtering and logging.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor a given process including which files are open and counters for the number of bytes written and read by using [python](http://python.org) + [psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) and log the results to a file at whatever rate you choose.

The psutil file io counters are in [Process io_counters()](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.io_counters) and there is the list of files open in [process open_files()](http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.open_files).

Both python and psutil are cross platform, free, open source tools.